# Write edited xml that replaced hypen with underscore

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

So I am trying to write a new xml file that I edited from the original by replacing the hyphen with an underscore and then start working on that xml file for the rest of the code.

This is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree

#attaching xml file
xmlfile = "hook_zap.xml"
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()

#replace hypen with underscore within the xml
doc = etree.parse(xmlfile)
for e in doc.xpath('//*[contains(local-name(),"-")]'):
  e.tag = e.tag.replace('-','_')
refracted = etree.tostring(doc, method='xml')

#create a new xml file with refracted file
refracted.write('base.xml')
#print (refracted)
```

And I keep getting this error:

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'write'

Answer (score 0):

Write `refracted` like any other kind data into a file:

```
with open('base.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(refracted.decode('utf-8'))
```